# Will my SEO rankings be penalized for duplicate content on my subdomain?

Tags: seo, google-search, wordpress, search-engines, duplicate-content

I have a site called www.xyz.com and it has a bunch of WordPress Blog posts on it ranking pretty well in google. The only issue is they want to move the blogs over to news.xyz.com (also a WP site). My question is, is it okay to put the exact same blogs on xyz.com onto news.xyz.com or will my site get penalized by Google?

Also, in the future could I post the same exact blog posts on xyz.com and news.xyz.com without it causing any issues or will I get duplicate content penalties?

Comment: Duplicate content is duplicate content. Only one of those pages can be the source of truth. You need to decide which one and make it the canonical source.

Comment: great thanks! i just wasnt sure because I believe Google is able to see subdomains as a part of the main domain so I didnt know if duplicate content did not apply to those but i appreciate the answer!

Comment: Duplicate content is calculated across domains on a URL by URL basis. So any content duplicated needs to have a canonical source regardless of where all of the duplicates exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `rel="canonical"` tags on your blogs so that only one is viewed by Google as being the "original", then you'll not be penalised. Not using canonical references is likely to harm your website's SEO.

This does mean you'll have next to no pagerank for these pages on your news.xyz.com subdomain if the blogs on the main xyz.com site are defined as the originals.

Here's Word of God on the matter:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en